# Remove item from array in UITableview

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, uitableview

What I'm trying to accomplish is when user selects an element for UITableView this element gets append to `servicioSeleccionado`array. But I'm stuck in this because if user decides to deselect the cell I want to remove that item from the array. I've try `anyarray.remove(at:)`but I can figure the way to tapp into that index. 
This is my code so far.

```
class ServicioHogarViewController: UIViewController{

    let serviciosHogar = [String](arrayLiteral: "Alfombras", "Muebles Madera", "Sillones", "Marmol", "Aplicación Teflón","Vestiduras", "Salas", "Colchones", "Sillas Oficinas")

    @IBOutlet weak var servicioHogarTB1: UITableView!

    var selectedIndex : Int? = nil

    var servicioSeleccionado : [String] = []

    @IBAction func doneButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "datePick2", sender: self)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        servicioHogarTB1.delegate = self
        servicioHogarTB1.dataSource = self
        servicioHogarTB1.register(UINib(nibName: "ServicioHogarCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "servicioCell1")
        servicioHogarTB1.separatorStyle = .none

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        print(servicioSeleccionado)
    }

}

// MARK : UITabeView Delegation

extension ServicioHogarViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return serviciosHogar.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == .checkmark {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
        } else {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }

        if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == .checkmark {
            servicioSeleccionado.append(serviciosHogar[indexPath.row])
            print(servicioSeleccionado)
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "servicioCell1", for: indexPath) as! ServicioHogarCell
            let servicio = serviciosHogar[indexPath.row]
            cell.servicioLabel.text = servicio
            return cell

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array :

```
var cast = ["Vivien", "Marlon", "Kim", "Karl"]
```

and you want to remove "Marlon" from it, you can find the index of Marlon using the `func firstIndex(of: Element) -> Int?` method for an array and then remove it like so :

```
if let index = cast.firstIndex(of: "Marlon"){
  cast.remove(at: index)
  print(cast)
}
```

That said, on `didSelectRowAt` run this function for your array and you'll accomplish what you're looking to.

Comment: Thank you very much It was of great help.